# Intercept the response of a webbrowser control without FiddlerCore in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser and it navigates to `http://example.com/`.
How can I intercept the request and change it before it gets rendered by the browser, not after?

Instead of rendering `Example Domain` as a title I want to render `Something Else`.

Can this be achieved without using a proxy? If not, what are the other alternatives to fiddler?

Comment: By Title do you mean the Link title in the Html Content ?

Comment: The one in <h1> tags, but anything after <!DOCTYPE html> should be fine for me. As realistically I'd like to change a javascript variable before rendering.

Comment: Navigating and Navigated event

Comment: @Steve Does the Navigated event trigger after the document has been downloaded, but before any javascript is executed?

Comment: try it yourself or read the document

Comment: @Steve but do you have the answer? I tried replacing the document text on navigating event, but it doesn't render at all.

Comment: Use `DocumentCompleted`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei is right. Use document completed event. Take the html from the webbrowser1.Document property, parse it, make whatever changes to it you want, and then set it again.

Comment: @RezaAghaei OK then it seems to be working with javascript. Thanks for the info.